# Connecting form that contains foreign keys to mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am begginer in php programming and Im tying to create an electronic medical reords system as a website where the admin registers patients and doctors and they are only able to login with the credentials they have been given.
So  far, I managed to ceate the admin dashboard, nabvbar, and functionalities like add new patient and add  new doctor.
**however i have problems with vital signs page. **
****# here is the scenario:
the doctor should be able to enter patient's vital signs info in the website and stor it in the database, then patient can view their vital sign record later.
i create this vital sign table:

```
`CREATE TABLE `vitalsigns`(  
`vital_id`int(11) NOT NULL,  
`patient_id`int(11) NOT NULL,
  `doctor_id`int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `temp`float NOT NULL,  
`heartRate`int(11) NOT NULL,  
`pulse`int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `bloodPressure`int(11) NOT NULL,  
`respiratoryRate`int(11) NOT NULL,  
`bloodOxygen`int(11) NOT NULL, 
 `date`date NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;`
```

```
CREATE TABLE `doctor` (
  `doctor_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `specialty` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `patient` (
  `patient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `lname` text NOT NULL,
  `email_address` varchar(170) NOT NULL,
  `phone_number` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `gender` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

i used phpmyadmin and assigned patient_id and doctor_id as foregin keys:

ALTER TABLE `vitalsigns`
ADD CONSTRAINT `vital_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`patient_id`) REFERENCES `patient` (`patient_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `vital_fk2` FOREIGN KEY (`doctor_id`) REFERENCES `doctor` (`doctor_id`);
COMMIT;

Whenever I try to add vital sign record by entering (patient_id, doctor_id, temperature, heart rate, pulse, bloodpressure, respiratory rate, blood oxygen, date) i got error message: patient Id is required !! please help me to fix this.

//code for vital_sign_add.php in adminfolder:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['admin_id']) && 
    isset($_SESSION['role'])) {

    if ($_SESSION['role'] == 'Admin') {
      
      include "../DB_connection.php";

       $pi = '';
       $di = '';
       $temp = '';
       $hr = '';
       $pulse = '';
       $bp = '';
       $rr = '';
       $bo = '';
      $date = '';

      if (isset($_GET['pi'])) $pi = $_GET['pi'];
      if (isset($_GET['di'])) $di = $_GET['di'];
       if (isset($_GET['temp'])) $temp = $_GET['temp'];
       if (isset($_GET['hr'])) $hr = $_GET['hr'];
       //if (isset($_GET['en'])) $en = $_GET['en'];
       if (isset($_GET['pulse'])) $pulse = $_GET['pulse'];
       if (isset($_GET['bp'])) $bp = $_GET['bp'];
       if (isset($_GET['rr'])) $rr = $_GET['rr'];
       if (isset($_GET['bo'])) $bo = $_GET['bo'];
       if (isset($_GET['date'])) $date = $_GET['date'];

       ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Admin - Add Vital Record</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="../logo.png">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        include "inc/navbar.php";
     ?>
     <div class="container mt-5">
        <a href="vital_sign.php"
           class="btn btn-dark">Go Back</a>

        <form method="post"
              class="shadow p-3 mt-5 form-w" 
              action="req/vital_sign_add.php">

        <h3>Add New Vital Sign Record</h3><hr>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>
          <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
           <?=$_GET['error']?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if (isset($_GET['success'])) { ?>
          <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
           <?=$_GET['success']?>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Patient Id</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$pi?>" 
                 name="patient_id">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Doctor Id</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$di?>"
                 name="doctor_id">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Temperature</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$temp?>"
                 name="temp">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Heart Rate</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$hr?>"
                 name="heartRate">
       
          
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Pulse</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$pulse?>"
                 name="pulse">
        
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Blood Pressure</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$bp?>"
                 name="bloodPressure">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Respiratory Rate</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$rr?>"
                 name="respiratoryRate">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Blood Oxygen</label>
          <input type="text" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value="<?=$bo?>"
                 name="bloodOxygen">
    
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label">Conducted Date</label>
          <input type="date" 
                 class="form-control"
                 value=""
                 name="date">
          <br>       
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
     </form>
     </div>
     
    
</body>
</html>
<?php 

  }else {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit;
  } 
}else {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit;
} 

?>
```

//code for vital_sign_add.php in requirements folder:

```
`include "../../DB_connection.php";
include "../data/vital_sign.php";

$pi = $_POST['patient_id'];
$di = $_POST['doctor_id'];
$temp = $_POST['temp'];
$hr = $_POST['heartRate'];
$pulse = $_POST['pulse'];
//$employee_number = $_POST['employee_number'];
$bp = $_POST['bloodPressure'];
$rr = $_POST['respiratoryRate'];
$bo = $_POST['bloodOxygen'];
$date = $_POST['date'];

$data = 'pi='.$patient_id.'&di='.$doctor_id.'&temp='.$temp.'&hr='.$heartRate.'&pulse='.$pulse.'&bp='.$bloodPressure.'&rr='.$respiratoryRate.'&bo='.$bloodOxygen.'&date='.$date;

if (empty($patient_id)) {
    $em  = "Patient ID is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($doctor_id)) {
    $em  = "Doctor ID is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($temp)) {
    $em  = "Temperature result is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($heartRate)) {
    $em  = "Heart Rate result is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($pulse)) {
    $em  = "Pulse result is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($bloodPressure)) {
    $em  = "Blood Pressure result is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($respiratoryRate)) {
    $em  = "Respiratory Rate result is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($bloodOxygen)) {
    $em  = "Blood Oxygen is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else if (empty($date)) {
    $em  = "Conducted Date is required";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?error=$em&$data");
    exit;
}else {

    $sql  = "INSERT INTO
             vitalsigns(patient_id, doctor_id, temp, hearRate, pulse, bloodPressure, respiratoryRate, bloodOxygen, date)
             VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([$pi, $di, $temp, $hr, $pulse, $bp, $rr, $bo, $date]);
    $sm = "New vital sign record has been registered successfully";
    header("Location: ../vital_sign_add.php?success=$sm");
    exit;
}`
```

Comment: In `vital_sign_add.php`, you never put any data into `$patient_id`, so `if (empty($patient_id))` is always true. Maybe you intended to use `$pi` for this instead?

Comment: "I am beginner ... and I'm tying to create an electronic medical records system" - I don't intend to mean any disrespect when I say this, but that is an arguably big task to take on, even for people that have been developing for decades. Do make sure that applicable laws are being followed from the start, specifically auditing. In some jurisdictions, you the developer could be fined (or worse) if your code allowed someone else to violate local laws related to this. For instance, if you are in the US you should look into HIPAA.

Comment: Agreed. Hopefully this is just a fictional scenario for some homework??

Comment: because the doctor suppose to enter the patient id number manually and system will store patient id and other vitals in vitalsigns table

Comment: this is just a homework project for college so don't worry,  I am fully aware of the complexity level of such tasks. My teacher just wants the website to be minimally functioning for educational purposes

Comment: Ok no problem. Did you understand my point about the $patient_id variable? Try using $pi instead

Comment: Variable names are free documentation to a certain degree, don't be afraid to be verbose. Using `pi` instead of `patient_id` or `patientId` or similar makes it harder to read, especially once you get "patient institute" and "parental indicator" which start with the same letters. If you want to make your life even easier, try to match your variables with your HTML names, so just use `patient_id` for both. Props to you and/or your curriculum for using prepared statements!